# General form of $\sqrt{a - b} - \sqrt{a + b}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, radicals

> General form of $\sqrt{a - b} - \sqrt{a + b}$?

What I would do is: let

$x = \sqrt{a - b} - \sqrt{a + b}$

$x^2 = 2a - 2\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}$

Then since $a + b > a - b$

$x = -\sqrt{2a - 2\sqrt{a^2 - b^2}}$

This is particularly useful in solving problem with nested square roots (like, let $a = 11, b = 2\sqrt{10}$

I am wondering, is there any other derivation and MORE WANTED: any simpler formula?

Comment: It depends on what one means by simpler. For that matter, the difference of two radicals looks simpler than the expression for $x$ with the nested radicals. One way to rewrite the expression that is occasionally useful follows from multiplying by $\frac{m}{m},$ where $m$ is the conjugate $\sqrt{a - b} + \sqrt{a + b}$---after some algebra, the numerator simplifies dramatically, at the cost of introducing a radical expression into the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Simpler" is dependent on the use made of the formula. For approximate calculations, the form
$$\frac{-2b}{\sqrt{a - b} \; + \; \sqrt{a + b}}$$
(obtained by multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a - b} \; + \; \sqrt{a + b}\,)$ is better when $|b|$ is very small in comparison to $|a|.$

Answer (score 0):

You want to calculate $u-v$ for $u$ and $v$ such that $u^2=a-b$ and $v^2=a+b$. Let us assume that $a>b$, i.e., $u,v>0$.

Then you have $u^2v^2=(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$ which leaves you with
$$uv=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}.$$

Then you have
$$(u-v)^2=u^2+v^2-2uv=2a-2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
and, knowing that $u<v$ and $u-v<0$, you get
$$u-v = \sqrt{2a-2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$

Similarly, you can use
$$(u+v)^2=u^2+v^2+2uv = 2a+2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
to calculate
$$u+v=\sqrt{2a+2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}.$$