# Evaluate the nested square root $x = \sqrt{11 - 2\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{11 + 2\sqrt{10}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math, radicals, nested-radicals

> Evaluate: $x = \sqrt{11 - 2\sqrt{10}} - \sqrt{11 + 2\sqrt{10}}$

You may have seen my other Q/A [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494304/general-form-of-sqrta-b-sqrta-b), but I am finding a different way, with perhaps perfect squares.

If we seperate,

$y = \sqrt{11 - 2\sqrt{10}}$. But this doesn't help.

Comment: Squaring is probably simplest. However, note that $11-2\sqrt{10}=(\sqrt{10}-1)^2$  and the other is $(\sqrt{10}+1)^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}x&=\sqrt{11-2\sqrt{10}}-\sqrt{11+2\sqrt{10}}\\&=\sqrt{10+1-2\sqrt{10\times 1}}-\sqrt{10+1+2\sqrt{10\times 1}}\\&=\sqrt{(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt 1)^2}-\sqrt{(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 1)^2}\\&=(\sqrt{10}-\sqrt 1)-(\sqrt{10}+\sqrt 1)\\&=-2\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

**HINT**
$x^2$ is easily computed using the difference of squares:

$$
(a+b)(a-b) = a^2 - b^2
$$

Comment: Yes I know this already, from the other thread. (+1)

Comment: when i see  square roots  i square it just to see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Another method  using the formula: 
$$\sqrt { a+\sqrt { b }  } =\sqrt { \frac { a+\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }-b }  }{ 2 }  } +\sqrt { \frac { a-\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }-b }  }{ 2 }  } \\ \sqrt { a-\sqrt { b }  } =\sqrt { \frac { a+\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }-b }  }{ 2 }  } -\sqrt { \frac { a-\sqrt { { a }^{ 2 }-b }  }{ 2 }  } $$
$$x=\sqrt { \frac { 11+\sqrt { 121-40 }  }{ 2 }  } -\sqrt { \frac { 11-\sqrt { 121-40 }  }{ 2 }  } -$$ $$\\ -\left[ \sqrt { \frac { 11+\sqrt { 121-40 }  }{ 2 }  } +\sqrt { \frac { 11-\sqrt { 121-40 }  }{ 2 }  }  \right] =$$ $$=-2\sqrt { \frac { 11-\sqrt { 121-40 }  }{ 2 }  } =-2$$